# Moment JS -- How to change format of edit boxes

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, format, momentjs

I have a Date/Time Field which has separate variants for dealing with Date, Time and both Date/Time.

In this question, I'll be focusing on the Time variant. We have a View page and an Edit page. This is the code for the Edit page.

```js
class TimePicker extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    
    this.onBlur = this.onBlur.bind(this);
    this.onFocus = this.onFocus.bind(this);
    }
        onBlur(event) {
        event.persist();
        clearTimeout(this.focusBlurTimeout);
        this.focusBlurTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({
                hasFocus: false,
            });
            if (this.props.onBlur && Object.prototype.toString.call(this.props.onBlur) == '[object Function]') {
        this.props.onBlur(event)
    }
          if(this.initialValue != this.props.value) {
                if (this.props.onBlurChange && Object.prototype.toString.call(this.props.onBlurChange) == '[object Function]') {
                    this.props.onBlurChange(event);
                }
        }
        }, 0);
    }
    
    onFocus(event) {
        clearTimeout(this.focusBlurTimeout);
        if (!this.state.hasFocus) {
            this.focusBlurTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
                this.setState({
                    hasFocus: true,
                });
                if (this.props.onFocus && Object.prototype.toString.call(this.props.onFocus) == '[object Function]') {
        this.props.onFocus(event)
    }
    this.initialValue = this.props.value;
            }, 0);
        }
    };
    
    render() {
        return (
            <span>
            <input className='form-control' 
            ref = {input => this.hourLeadingZero = input}
            name='hour' 
            value={this.props.value && this.props.value.hourLeadingZero ? this.props.value.hourLeadingZero : ''} 
            type='number' 
            style={{width: '4em'}} 
            onChange={this.props.onChange}
   onFocus={this.onFocus}
   onBlur={this.onBlur}
            min='1' 
            max='12' 
            placeholder='12' 
            />:
            <input 
            ref = {input => this.minute = input}
            className='form-control' 
            name='min' 
            value={this.props.value && this.props.value.minute ? this.props.value.minute : ''} 
            type='number' 
            style={{width: '4em'}} 
            onChange={this.props.onChange} 
   onFocus={this.onFocus}
   onBlur={this.onBlur}
            min='0' 
            max='59' 
            placeholder='00' 
            />
            <select className='form-control' 
            ref = {select => this.AMPMUppercase = select}
            name='meridiem' 
            onChange={this.props.onChange} 
   onFocus={this.onFocus}
   onBlur={this.onBlur}
            value={this.props.value && this.props.value.AMPMUppercase ? this.props.value.AMPMUppercase : ''}
            >
                <option value='AM'>AM</option>
                <option value='PM'>PM</option>
            </select>
            </span>
            );
    }
}

class TimezoneSelector extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    
    this.onBlur = this.onBlur.bind(this);
    this.onFocus = this.onFocus.bind(this);
 }
    
    onBlur(event) {
        event.persist();
        clearTimeout(this.focusBlurTimeout);
        this.focusBlurTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({
                hasFocus: false,
            });
            if (this.props.onBlur && Object.prototype.toString.call(this.props.onBlur) == '[object Function]') {
        this.props.onBlur(event)
    }
          if(this.initialValue != this.props.value) {
                if (this.props.onBlurChange && Object.prototype.toString.call(this.props.onBlurChange) == '[object Function]') {
                    this.props.onBlurChange(event);
                }
        }
        }, 0);
    }
    
    onFocus(event) {
        clearTimeout(this.focusBlurTimeout);
        if (!this.state.hasFocus) {
            this.focusBlurTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
                this.setState({
                    hasFocus: true,
                });
                if (this.props.onFocus && Object.prototype.toString.call(this.props.onFocus) == '[object Function]') {
        this.props.onFocus(event)
    }
    this.initialValue = this.props.value;
            }, 0);
        }
    }
    
      render() {
        return (
            <span>
            <select className='form-control' 
            ref = {select => this.timezone = select}
            name='timezoneselection' 
            onChange={this.props.onChange} 
   onFocus={this.onFocus}
   onBlur={this.onBlur}
            value={this.props.value && this.props.value.timezone ? this.props.value.timezone : moment.tz.guess()}
            >
            <option value="America/Chicago">Central</option>
   <option value="Pacific/Honolulu">Hawaiian</option>
   <option value="America/Nome">Alaska</option>
   <option value="America/Los_Angeles">Pacific</option>
   <option value="America/Denver">Mountain</option>
            <option value="America/Phoenix">Mountain-Arizona</option>
            <option value="America/New_York">Eastern</option>
            </select> 
            </span> 
        );
    }
}


export default class timeEdit extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={
         date: ((this.props.value && this.props.value.date) ? moment(this.props.value.date) : null)
    }; 
        this.componentWillUnmount = this.componentWillUnmount.bind(this);
        this.onBlur = this.onBlur.bind(this);
        this.onFocus = this.onFocus.bind(this);
        this.updateValues = this.updateValues.bind(this);
    }
    
      updateValues(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var val = this.props.value ? Object.assign({},this.props.value) : {};
        var hour = val.hour || 0;
        hour = Math.min(Math.max(Math.trunc(hour), 1), 12);
        var min = val.minute || 0;
        min = Math.min(Math.max(Math.trunc(min), 0), 59);
        var sec = val.second || 0;
        sec = Math.min(Math.max(Math.trunc(sec), 0), 59);
        var meridiem = val.AMPMUppercase || 'AM';
        var timezoneselection = val.timezone;
        var name = event.target.name;
        var nameVal;
        switch(name) {
            case 'hour':
                nameVal = hour = Math.min(Math.max(Math.trunc(event.target.value), 1), 12);
            break;
            case 'min':
                nameVal = min = Math.min(Math.max(Math.trunc(event.target.value), 0), 59);
            break;
            case 'meridiem':
                nameVal = meridiem = event.target.value
            break;
            case 'timezoneselection':
                nameVal = timezoneselection = event.target.value
            break;
        }
        var timeStamp = (hour || 12) + ':' + (min || 0) + ' ' + (meridiem || 'AM') + ' ' + (timezoneselection || '');
        var newMoment = moment(timeStamp, 'h:m:s A ');
        val.moment = (val.moment ? moment(val.moment) : moment()).tz(timezoneselection || 'America/Chicago').hours(newMoment.hours()).minutes(newMoment.minutes()).seconds(newMoment.seconds());
        val.timestamp = val.moment.format('X');
        val.AMPMUppercase = val.moment.format('A');
        val.AMPMLowercase = val.moment.format('a');
        val.timezone = timezoneselection;
        val.hour = val.moment.format('h');
        val.hourLeadingZero = val.moment.format('hh');
        val.hour24 = val.moment.format('HH');
        val.minute = val.moment.format('mm');
        val.second = val.moment.format('ss');
        val.time = val.moment.format(this.props.timeFormat || 'LT');
        val.fullField = (val.date ? val.date + ' ' : '') + val.time;
        val.timeTimestamp = parseInt(val.hour24) * 60 * 60 + parseInt(val.minute) * 60 + (parseInt(val.second) || 0);
        val.moment = val.moment.format();
        this.props.onChange({
            target:{
                value: val
            }
        });
    }
  
getInitialState() {
        return {};
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearTimeout(this.focusBlurTimeout);
    }
    
    onBlur(event) {
        event.persist();
        clearTimeout(this.focusBlurTimeout);
        this.focusBlurTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({
                hasFocus: false,
            });
            if (this.props.onBlur && Object.prototype.toString.call(this.props.onBlur) == '[object Function]') {
        this.props.onBlur(event)
    }
          if(this.initialValue != this.props.value) {
                if (this.props.onBlurChange && Object.prototype.toString.call(this.props.onBlurChange) == '[object Function]') {
                    this.props.onBlurChange(event);
                }
        }
        }, 0);
    }
    
    onFocus(event) {
        clearTimeout(this.focusBlurTimeout);
        if (!this.state.hasFocus) {
            this.focusBlurTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
                this.setState({
                    hasFocus: true,
                });
                if (this.props.onFocus && Object.prototype.toString.call(this.props.onFocus) == '[object Function]') {
        this.props.onFocus(event)
    }
    this.initialValue = this.props.value;
            }, 0);
        }
    }
 
  render() {
    return (
        <span>
            <span className='form-inline' aria-required={(this.props.required) ? true : false} onClick={this.props.onClick} onMouseEnter={this.props.onMouseOver} onMouseLeave={this.props.onMouseOut}>
                <span>
                    <TimePicker 
                    value={this.props.value || {hourLeadingZero: '', minute: '', AMPMUppercase: 'AM'}} 
                    onChange={this.updateValues}
                    onFocus={this.onFocus}
                    onBlur={this.onBlur}/>
                    {(this.props.allowTimezone) ?
                 <TimezoneSelector
     value={this.props.value || {timezone: ' '}}
                    onChange={this.updateValues}
                    onBlur={this.onBlur} 
                    onFocus={this.onFocus}/> : null}
            </span>
            </span>
            <small className='form-text text-muted'>{this.props.descriptiveText}</small>
        </span>
        );
  }
}
```

This is the code for the View page which will display what you entered in the Edit page.

```
export default class timeView extends Component {
  render() {
        var value = '';
      if (this.props.value) {
          if (this.props.value.moment) {
              var timeFormat = this.props.timeFormat || 'LT';
              var momentObj = moment(this.props.value.moment);
              if (this.props.value && this.props.value.timezone) {
                  momentObj.tz(this.props.value.timezone);
              }
              value =  momentObj.format(timeFormat);
          } else if (this.props.value.time) {
              value = this.props.value.time;
          }
      }

    var toDisplay = {
        'America/Chicago' : 'Central',
        'Pacific/Honolulu' : 'Hawaiian',
        'America/Nome' : 'Alaska',
        'America/Los_Angeles' : 'Pacific',
        'America/Denver' : 'Mountain',
        'America/Phoenix' : 'Eastern'
    }


        return (
            <p className='form-control-static'>
                {value}
                &nbsp;
                {this.props.value && this.props.value.timezone ? toDisplay[this.props.value.timezone] || null : null}
            </p>
        );
  }
}
```

View works and will reformat the input (IE: if you enter 2 PM, it'll come out as 2:00 PM in View; if you enter 2 PM and enter HH:mm for TimeFormat you'll get 14:00.)

I need the Edit variant to also take the TimeFormat setting into affect. IE: Right now it's 'Hour:Minute AM/PM'. If I set Timeformat as 'HH' I would want this to change to '24Hour'

Would regular expressions be the way to go with this? How could I possibly use those for this? I'm not that well acquainted with Regex.

I attempted this code in the TimePicker component for Edit as well, but that didn't pan out and returns undefined in the console.

```
class TimePicker extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    this.onBlur = this.onBlur.bind(this);
    this.onFocus = this.onFocus.bind(this);
    }
        onBlur(event) {
        event.persist();
        clearTimeout(this.focusBlurTimeout);
        this.focusBlurTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({
                hasFocus: false,
            });
            if (this.props.onBlur && Object.prototype.toString.call(this.props.onBlur) == '[object Function]') {
                    this.props.onBlur(event)
                }
          if(this.initialValue != this.props.value) {
                if (this.props.onBlurChange && Object.prototype.toString.call(this.props.onBlurChange) == '[object Function]') {
                    this.props.onBlurChange(event);
                }
        }
        }, 0);
    }

    onFocus(event) {
        clearTimeout(this.focusBlurTimeout);
        if (!this.state.hasFocus) {
            this.focusBlurTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
                this.setState({
                    hasFocus: true,
                });
                if (this.props.onFocus && Object.prototype.toString.call(this.props.onFocus) == '[object Function]') {
                    this.props.onFocus(event)
                }
                this.initialValue = this.props.value;
            }, 0);
        }
    };

    render() {
        var hourFormat = (this.props.timeFormat && this.props.timeFormat.includes('HH')) ?
        ( <input className='form-control'
            ref = {input => this.hour24 = input}
            name='hour' 
            value={this.props.value && this.props.value.hour24 ? this.props.value.hour24 : ''} 
            type='number' 
            style={{width: '4em'}} 
            onChange={this.props.onChange}
            onFocus={this.onFocus}
            onBlur={this.onBlur}
            min='1' 
            max='24' 
            placeholder='24' 
            />) :
            (<input className='form-control'
            ref = {input => this.hourLeadingZero = input}
            name='hour' 
            value={this.props.value && this.props.value.hourLeadingZero ? this.props.value.hourLeadingZero : ''} 
            type='number' 
            style={{width: '4em'}} 
            onChange={this.props.onChange}
            onFocus={this.onFocus}
            onBlur={this.onBlur}
            min='1' 
            max='12' 
            placeholder='12' 
            />);
            console.log(this.props.timeFormat && this.props.timeFormat.includes('HH'));
        return (
            <span>
            {hourFormat}
            :
            <input 
            ref = {input => this.minute = input}
            className='form-control' 
            name='min' 
            value={this.props.value && this.props.value.minute ? this.props.value.minute : ''} 
            type='number' 
            style={{width: '4em'}} 
            onChange={this.props.onChange} 
            onFocus={this.onFocus}
            onBlur={this.onBlur}
            min='0' 
            max='59' 
            placeholder='00' 
            />
            <select className='form-control' 
            ref = {select => this.AMPMUppercase = select}
            name='meridiem' 
            onChange={this.props.onChange} 
            onFocus={this.onFocus}
            onBlur={this.onBlur}
            value={this.props.value && this.props.value.AMPMUppercase ? this.props.value.AMPMUppercase : ''}
            >
                <option value='AM'>AM</option>
                <option value='PM'>PM</option>
            </select>
            </span>
            );
    }
}
```

Any and all help would be appreciated!